# Having .htaccess No-Cache problems with Safari 5.1

Tags: .htaccess, safari

I am trying to make it so that if anyone tries to download a swf file from my site (by going to http://mywebsite.com/direct.swf, for instance) they can't, they are just redirected to the homepage on my site.

The following directives work great for this on all other browsers:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(swf)$">
   FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header unset ETag
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
   Header set Pragma "no-cache"
   Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(my\.)?website.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(swf)$ http://website.com [NC,R,L]
```

And it was working on Safari before I upgraded to Safari 5. Now what happens is that if I load a url with the embedded swf you just see a white page and if you check the activity monitor, only 2.6kb of the swf loaded. On all other browsers the url loads normally (You can see the swf).

Anyone have an idea what's going wrong and how I can fix?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Safari is newly broken.  You may need to file a bug with Apple.